# Clicking a button on a popup using selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am learning selenium and I am trying to close this popup on this particular website

This is my code:

```
hindustan_times = "https://www.hindustantimes.com/cricket/shadab-khan-brutally-shuts-bcci-chief-selector-ajit-agarkar-savage-virat-kohli-will-take-care-pakistan-pacers-asia-cup-101693104511746.html"
import time
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
url = hindustan_times
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element("xpath",'//*[@id="deny"]').click()
```

but I am getting this error
`Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="deny"]"}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Root cause:**

The desired element is wrapped within an IFRAME, see the screenshot below. In such cases, you need the driver context to switch into IFRAME first, then perform `click()` action. See the full code below with in-line explanation.

[image]

**Working code with explanation:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
url = "https://www.hindustantimes.com/cricket/shadab-khan-brutally-shuts-bcci-chief-selector-ajit-agarkar-savage-virat-kohli-will-take-care-pakistan-pacers-asia-cup-101693104511746.html"
driver.get(url)
# Below line will create an object of WebDriverWait
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
# Below line will switch into the iframe
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID, "webpush-onsite")))
# Below line will click on "I'll do this later" button
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(("xpath",'//*[@id="deny"]'))).click()
# Below line will come out of IFRAME
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```